# Array Index Out of Bounds Exception and I don't know why

Tags: java, list, indexoutofboundsexception

I don't understand why this is going out of bounds, can you help me?

What should happen:

- user inputs length of list
- user inputs all items in the list, only prompted until the user-inputed length of list (a) is reached.

For some reason after the first item in the list it goes out of bounds but I can't tell why.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner

public class project2 {

public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for input

    int a = 0;
    double [] lista = new double [a]; //create array
    double [] listb = new double [a]; //create array

    System.out.println("How long are the lists? ");
    System.out.print("(The lists should be the same length):  ");
    a = input.nextInt();

    int count=1;
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for list A:");
    for(int j = 0; j < a-1 ; j++){ //user input numbers loop into array "list"
        System.out.print(count + ": ");
        lista[j] = input.nextDouble();
        count++;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int a = 0;double [] lista = new double [a]; double [] listb = new double [a];` What do you think it does?

Comment: what, those arrays and int?

Comment: The int is the length of the arrays, the "lista" and "listb" are going to be two separate lists that i will later use. I only have the code for inputing info for lista posted up there, though

Comment: @user3420212 *"The int is the length of the arrays."* Yes; also, the int is 0. Therefore... :)

Comment: But you're thinking that changing the value of `a` after declaring those array will change their lengths. This is not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare your `lista` and `listb` arrays, you use `a` as the length, but at that time, it's `0`.  You haven't assigned the user's value to `a` yet.

Create your arrays *after* you have the length from the input.

```
a = input.nextInt();

double [] lista = new double [a]; //create array
double [] listb = new double [a]; //create array
```

Answer (score 3):

you created array with 0 element and if you enter any number for a which is greater than 1 it will attempt to look at index 1 which is out of bound